# Issue with fullscreen video in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to play embedded videos (youtube,vimeo,facebook,mp4) in a webview.
I can play all except one case, youtube videos fullscreen in landscape mode.
I have seen many answers on this problem but I can not find a solution to my case.
I already tried put in the manifest.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and I'm using `onShowCustomView()`, `onHideCustomView()` from [this website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1dkJXjuTsg).

I saw a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085952/youtube-video-played-in-webview-shows-black-screen-when-taken-to-fullscreen) with no replies.
When youtube video goes to fullscreen the screen turns black and I can only hear the sound of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - make custom implementation of WebChromeClient

```
class MyWebChromeClient extends (android.webkit.WebChromeClient as {new (): any}) {
        constructor() {
            super();
            return global.__native(this);
        }

        onShowCustomView(view: android.view.View, callback: android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
        }

        onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();
        }
    }
```

Then you can do

```
let myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
this.webView.android.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my problem, I have a similar code, I find out that the problem is only with some youtube videos, I think the problem is with aspect ratio, if the video is 4:3 work fine in fullscreen else the video turns black.